# Why does this code fail to modify MongoDB user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have this code that fetches a team's schedule from an excel file and what I want to do afterward is to add those shifts to the user's in MongoDB. Right now it adds them to an object and from that object, I tried to add it to the user's shifts field in MongoDB and I also tried to add it directly without using an intermediary object. But nothing happens.

I get no error anywhere. The only thing I noticed is that the console.log doesn't seem to run anymore when I have the user code added. Not sure what went wrong here.

```
const ExcelJS = require("exceljs");
const moment = require("moment");
const User = require("../../models/User");

let date = moment("01.06.2020", "DD-MM-YYYY");

const shifts = {

};

times = {
  "9-18": {
    start: moment("9:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
    end: moment("18:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
  },
  "12-21": {
    start: moment("12:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
    end: moment("21:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
  },
  "10-14": {
    start: moment("10:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
    end: moment("14:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
  },
  "9-16": {
    start: moment("9:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
    end: moment("116:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
  },
  "15-21": {
    start: moment("15:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
    end: moment("21:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
  },
  "21-1": {
    start: moment("21:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
    end: moment("1:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
  },
  "21-6": {
    start: moment("21:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
    end: moment("6:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
  },
  "00-9": {
    start: moment("00:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
    end: moment("9:00:00", "HH:mm:ss").format("hh:mm A"),
  },
  DO: { start: "DO", end: "DO" },
  CO: { start: "CO", end: "CO" },
};

const readxl = async () => {
  const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
  const file = await workbook.xlsx.readFile("../../June.xlsx");
  const worksheet = file.getWorksheet("June");
  const user = await User.findById("5ee8c995f68af9783014b3f0");
  let cell = 5;
  let row = 9;
  let name = 4;

  while (true) {
    let rows = worksheet.getRow(row);
    if (row === 35) {
      break;
    } else if (row === 19) {
      row = 28;
    } else if (row === 31) {
      row = 33;
    } else if (cell === 35) {
      date.subtract(30, "day");
      row += 1;
      console.log(row);
      cell = 5;
    }

    while (true) {
      if (cell === 35) {
        break;
      }

      if (!shifts[rows.getCell(name).value]) {
        shifts[rows.getCell(name).value] = [];
      }

      if (!shifts[rows.getCell(name).value][date]) {
        shifts[rows.getCell(name).value][date] = [];
      }

      shifts[rows.getCell(name).value][date].push({
        start: times[rows.getCell(cell).value].start,
        end: times[rows.getCell(cell).value].end,
      });
      //   shifts[rows.getCell(name).value].push({
      //     [date]: {
      //       start: times[rows.getCell(cell).value].start,
      //       end: times[rows.getCell(cell).value].end,
      //     },
      //   });

      cell++;
      date.add(1, "days");
    }
  }

  user.shifts.push(shifts["user1"]);

  user.save();
  console.log(shifts);
};

readxl();
```

**Edit: I have been able to fix it, partially using this code instead. The problem i have now is that it duplicates the dates/shifts for each user. The object itself has no duplicate but on the mongoDB side it does.

Edit2: actually, only the first user in the list gets duplicate entries, weird...**

```
while (true) {
  let rows = worksheet.getRow(row);
  if (row === 35) {
    break;
  } else if (row === 19) {
    row = 28;
  } else if (row === 31) {
    row = 33;
  } else if (cell === 35) {
    date.subtract(30, "day");
    row += 1;
    console.log(row);
    cell = 5;
  }

  while (true) {
    if (cell === 35) {
      break;
    }

    shifts[rows.getCell(name).value].push({
      [date]: {
        start: times[rows.getCell(cell).value].start,
        end: times[rows.getCell(cell).value].end,
      },
    });

    cell++;
    date.add(1, "days");
  }
}
console.log(shifts);
const newSchedule = new Schedule({
  shifts: shifts,
});
newSchedule.save().then((schedule) => {
  res.send(schedule);
});
```

Comment: Without having a detailed look at your code - are you sure that both of your  `while(true)` loops terminate at some point?

Comment: Yes, if i remove the mongoDB part from the code everything works fine. I can console.log the shifts object and see that all the shifts from the excel file have been added correctly. As soon as i introduce the MongoDB code, nothing seems to happen. I don't even get an error or the app crashing, it just runs, ends and then nothing.

Comment: Ok, can you add the code for `User.save()`?

Comment: i added an edit, i got it to work but i'm getting duplicates for some reason.

Comment: actually, only the first user in the list gets duplicate entries, weird...

Comment: i figured it out, the row incrementing was at the wrong step in the code. it's ok now

Answer (score 0):

It fails to modify the user because `findById` returns a promise

```
 const user = await User.findById("5ee8c995f68af9783014b3f0");
  user.exec((err,user)=>{//....})
```

or put your code inside the callback function

```
    const user = await User.findById({"5ee8c995f68af9783014b3f0"},(err,user)=>{
          // your code goes here 
     user.save()
});
```

Comment: He awaits the promise returned from `findById()` - I don't think that's the issue here...

Comment: yes but to consume the promise he has to use `then` or `exec ` and i don't see any in the code

Comment: Yes await is not the issue. I noticed that if i console.log the shifts object i get something in the console but if i try to use that object, it's empty. When i try to save values from the object to MongoDB, nothing happens because the shifts object is empty. For example, i used the code in an api enpoint to test and when i send a get request, it will console.log the object and i can see all the values there but i also send the object as a response and it's an empty object. Why?

Comment: I think Sven is right and I was mistaken - it should actually be `const user = await User.findById(..).exec()`

Comment: I did but it still doesn't save anything to the user. The issue is somewhere else. Like i said above, i can console.log the shifts object but i can't use it. I can't iterate over it, i get nothing, i can't use data from it, i can't do anything other than console.log it. It's like data disappears along the way.